# Open cart image upload gives trouble

Tags: php, image-processing, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I have one image it have high resolution [[image: image1] when i try to upload this image this gives problem ..if i reduce its resolution using photoshop .i can able to upload the same image this is the reduced resolution image properties [image] pls find the original image [image] and edited image[image]

now i want to know why i cant upload this image in opencart is tat because of high resolution ???? if so how can update my resolution in opencart???

and when am trying to upload ths image in ftp i cant able to upload..

Comment: whats the error it is showing ?

Comment: Suggestion: if the problem is not related to, or does not involve programming, it might be best to post this question on [Web Application Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [User User Stack Exchange](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: @vicky: it got stucked

Comment: and its related to programming only i really dont knw where they are restricting resolution in opencart